# Scala: Making higher kinded type with some generic type

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, higher-kinded-types

For example I have defined a `Monad Trait` like this:

```
trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def unit[T](a: => T): F[T]
  def flatMap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]
}
```

I create a `ListMonad` that implement above interface:

```
 class ListMonad extends Monad[List] {
    override def unit[T](a: => T): List[T] = List(a)

    override def flatMap[A, B](fa: List[A])(f: (A) => List[B]): List[B] = fa flatMap f
  }
```

Now I want to verify above Monad in "Generic way". First attribute of monad is `Left Identity`. That means: if we giving a monad "m", an value " x"and a function "f". It should satisfied: `m.(identity(x)).flatMap(f) == f(x)`

So for example I create following verifier class for checking that assumption:

```
case class MonadVerifier[A, F[_]](monad: Monad[F[_]])(f: A => F[A]) {
  def leftIdentity(value: A): Boolean =
    monad.flatMap[A, A](monad.unit(value))(f) == f(value)
}
```

In this code, I meet error:

> Type mismatch. expected: (A) => F[_][A], actual: (A) => F[A]

I don't know in Scala, how can I express `F[A]` as generic. I think if I defined `F[_]` Scala will insert generic type into `[_]` when calling `F[A]` but it isn't true.

Please help me in this case. Thanks

Comment: Changing `monad: Monad[F[_]]` to `monad: Monad[F]` should do it ...

Answer (score 3):

What @Dima said:

The error is that

```
MonadVerifier[A, F[_]](monad: Monad[F[_]])
```

should be

```
MonadVerifier[A, F[_]](monad: Monad[F])
```

What the first line is saying is not that `F` is a monad (`F` has kind `* -> *` and values of type `F[_]`), but that `F[_]` (that is, type constructor `F` applied to any type of the right kind) is a monad, (`F` has kind `* -> (* -> *)` and values of type `F[_][_]`).

Expanding on that (ignore this if you want): `Monad` expects its type argument to take one type argument and return a concrete type. The argument to `Monad` is said to have kind `* -> *` ("function" from concrete types to concrete types), and `Monad` itself has kind `(* -> *) -> *` ("function" from "functions" from concrete types to concrete types to concrete types). When you say `Monad[F[_]]`, you imply that the argument (`F[_]`) has kind `* -> *`, because that's the kind `Monad` expects. `F[_]` is the application of a type constructor `F` (kind `a -> b` for some unknown kinds `a` and `b`) to any concrete type (implied by `_`, forcing the kind of `F` to be constrained to `* -> k` for some unknown `k`). Since `F[_]` also has to be `* -> *` because of `Monad`, this constrains `k = (* -> *)` and so `F` is forced to be of kind `* -> (* -> *)` which is the curried version of `(*, *) -> *`. This implies that `F` has two type parameters, and it is monadic in the second one (like `Either`).

In the future, maybe use a context bound to avoid similar mixups:

```
MonadVerifier[A, F[_]: Monad] // no params needed
```

Comment: I think, you would still have to use the type annotation in the code with something like `val monad = implicitly[Monad[F]] ` ... unless you are willing to reference it as `evidence$1` in the code :/

Comment: Not if you use implicits to add the monad functions to the base type, but otherwise yes.